# Use Rule with in a Rule in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need help. I am new in prolog and i haven't get used around with it. I wanted to get the remaining subjects with level 2 that joe did not get to enrolled to.
with these facts in prolog:

```
enrolled(joe,science).
enrolled(joe,math).

subjects(math, 2).
subject(science, 2).
subject(history,2).
subject(music, 2).
subject(health,3).
subject(literature,3).
```

My desired output is [history, music]. I made have this rule with combination of subtract and findall built in predicate but did not work. Can there be another possible solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: Why not show the code that you tried? If you are using `findall` you should do your solution in steps. First, write a predicate, `subjects_i_want(S)` that will be true if `S` is a subject that is level 2, and `joe` did not enroll in subject `S`. To write such a predicate, you only have to convert that statement into Prolog. Then you run `findall` on that predicate.

Comment: @mbratch i did it like this. get_subject_available(Name,X) :- subtract( subjects(N, 2), findall(X0, enrolled(Name, X0), X).

Comment: You should show that code in your problem statement. But that syntax is not proper prolog syntax. You can't embed predicate queries inside of other predicate queries as you are attempting, unless the predicate is designed to handle them. You haven't defined `subtract/2`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about subtract/2 (do you mean intersection ?).
Anyway, you should get the required list with findall/3:

```
get_subject_available(Name, X) :-
  findall(S, (subject(S,2), \+enrolled(Name,S)), X).
```